# Are memory mapped files managed by the OS?

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

I have been reading about memory mapped files and I had a couple of questions:

1. Are they operating system managed or do they exist within the JVM heap and therefore are subject to garbage collection.
2. If they are operating system managed, and I know this is OS dependent, but is it likely that if I have two processes (Java or not) that memory map a file, that they are going to be looking at the same bit of memory. (ie. Given a 1MB file, if 10 processes memory map it, it still only uses ~1MB of memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact implementation of memory mapped files is intentionally unspecified but the obvious intention is that if the operating system provides such a capability, it is used for implementing it.

Thus, for most operating systems and JVMs, the `MappedByteBuffer` is just a wrapper around the logical memory returned by the operating system’s function for memory mapping. It is still subject to garbage collection; if the last front end byte buffer pointing to the mapped region got collected, the implementation will take care to release the mapping.

If the operating system provides shared access to a file region via the same physical memory page, the typical Java implementations of memory mapped files will exhibit that behavior. This is in fact the most straight-forward way of implementing shared memory between processes in Java; just letting each process map the same region of the same temporary file…

Comment: Ah so the actual memory that is mapped (lets say its 2GB) itself doesn't exist on the heap, only the "pointers" (`MappedByteBuffer`) do - so effectively, I will have something, but not the whole 2GB on my heap.

Comment: Right, actually, the memory mapping is fighting with the heap for the logical address space which is relevant for 32 Bit JVMs, the bigger the heap maximum setting, the lesser the logical address space available to memory mapping.